# Data table is not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Below is my boostrap data table `staff_look`. It contain about 50 records when page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#staff_look').DataTable({
                'ordering': true,
                'lengthMenu': [10, 25, 50, 75, 100]
            });
        });
```

When a button click i remove all rows and append new rows to table body.

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url('controller/function') ?>", {'id': id},
    function (data)
    {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $('#tbl_body').find('tr').remove();
            for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                $('#tbl_body').append("<tr><td>" + (j + 1) + "</td><td>" + data[j]['reg_no'] + "</td><td>" + data[j]['first_name'] + " " + data[j]['last_name'] + "</td><td>" + data[j]['nic_no'] + "</td></tr>");
            }
        }
    },
    "json"
    );
```

But the **Showing 1 to 10 of 50 entries** and table next and previous section in data table dos't change when i remove rows and append rows. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider below example

For deleting row

```
$('#staff_look').DataTable().remove().draw( false );
```

For Adding new Row

```
$('#example').DataTable().row.add( [
            (j + 1),
            data[j]['reg_no'],
            data[j]['first_name'],
            data[j]['last_name'],
            data[j]['nic_no'] 
        ] ).draw( false );
```